# I can't find the answer I want for a particular question (java)

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumAverage2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("average program");
        System.out.println("Enter multiple integers greater than or equal to 0.");
        System.out.println("Enter a negative integer to finish the entry.");
        
        boolean end = false;
        int n;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        
        while(!end) {
            n = input.nextInt();
            if (n>=0) {
                sum = sum + n;
                count++;
            }else
                end = true;
        }
        
        double average ;
        average = (double) sum / (double) count ;
        System.out.println("Number of integers greater than 0 entered  = " + count);
        System.out.println("sum of integers = " + sum);
        System.out.printf("average = %.2f", + average);
        
        input.close();
    }

}
```

I'm trying to solve this problem, but the answer I want doesn't come out under certain conditions.

If I enter

3  7  1  -1

**average program**

**Enter multiple integers greater than or equal to 0.**

**Enter a negative integer to finish the entry.**

**Number of integers greater than 0 entered = 3**

**sum of integers = 11**

**average = 3.67**

//
I made a program that comes out with this answer.

However, the condition "Do not output the sum and average if the user inputs a negative integer from the beginning" must be satisfied, but the code above does not work.

If I enter -10

**average program**

**Enter multiple integers greater than or equal to 0.**

**Enter a negative integer to finish the entry.**

**Number of integers greater than 0 entered = 0**

**sum of integers = 0**
**average = NaN**

//
The answer comes as above.

The answer i want is
//

**average program**

**Enter multiple integers greater than or equal to 0.**

**Enter a negative integer to finish the entry.**

**Number of integers greater than 0 entered = 0**
//

I've only been learning to code for 2 weeks, so I'm having a lot of difficulties. I'd be very grateful if you guys could help me.

Wrong answer
press -10
//

**average program**

**Enter multiple integers greater than or equal to 0.**

**Enter a negative integer to finish the entry.**

**Number of integers greater than 0 entered = 0**

**sum of integers = 0**

**average = NaN**

Correct answer
press -10
//

**average program**

**Enter multiple integers greater than or equal to 0.**

**Enter a negative integer to finish the entry.**

**Number of integers greater than 0 entered = 0**

I want to solve a problem that does not work under certain conditions.

Comment: In future, please use a title that reflects the actual problem you're having.  Perhaps 'how to avoid printing results in some cases?'. We can guess you can't find an answer, otherwise you wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: It was my first time so I didn't know. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: No problem. The idea is that, if someone else has a similar problem in the future, your title might help them to find the existing solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `count` is the number of numbers entered.

Wrap all the 'printing sum and average' stuff in 'if count > 0'.

```
System.out.println("Number of integers greater than 0 entered  = " + count);
if (count > 0) {
    double average = (double) sum / (double) count;
    System.out.println("sum of integers = " + sum);
    System.out.printf("average = %.2f", + average);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a boolean flag set as false in the beginning. Set the flag as true when the n>=0. And the end, if the flag is true, print the average.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumAverage2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("average program");
        System.out.println("Enter multiple integers greater than or equal to 0.");
        System.out.println("Enter a negative integer to finish the entry.");
        
        boolean end = false;
        boolean flag = false;
        int n;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        
        while(!end) {
            n = input.nextInt();
            if (n>=0) {
                sum = sum + n;
                count++;
                flag = true;
            }else
                end = true;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Number of integers greater than 0 entered  = " + count);
        if(flag){
           double average ;
           average = (double) sum / (double) count ;
           System.out.println("sum of integers = " + sum);
           System.out.printf("average = %.2f", + average);
        }
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: No need for an extra indicator; 'count > 0' already fills that role.